# How to write a if and else statement for a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to know how i can write an if and else statement for a vector. So let's say i have a vector which includes 1,2,3,4,5. I want the if statement to return a string if the number 1 is inside the vector. I know how to structure it but how do i write the statement. I have writen an example below with question marks because I'm unsure what is supposed to be in the brackets.

```
vector <int> myvec {1,2,3,4,5};
if (myvec??? 1) [
cout << "yes it is there" << endl;

]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::vector<int> myvec {1,2,3,4,5};
if (std::find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 1) != myvec.end()) {
    std::cout << "yes it is there" << std::endl;
}
```

In C++23, there is even [`std::ranges::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains):

```
if (std::ranges::contains(myvec, 1)) {
    std::cout << "yes it is there" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, +1 .I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Various options.   One is

```
 if (std::count(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 1) > 0)
 {
      cout << "yes it is there" << endl;
 }
```

This will detect the presence of one or more elements with value `1`.   If you want to test if there is *exactly* one element with value `1`, change the `> 0` to `== 1`.

Comment: The downside is that `std::count()` has to iterate the entire vector, whereas `std::find()` stops when it finds the 1st match

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if (std::find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 1) != myvec.end()) {
   ...
}
```

I think it will be better to use a function that expresses what you want to do.

```
if ( vector_contains_item(myvec, 1) ) {
   ...
}
```

You push the details of the logic to the function.

```
bool vector_contains_item(std::vector<int> const& myvec, int item)
{
    return (std::find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), item) != myvec.end());
}
```

Comment: I would take it a step further. Make `vector_contains_item()` be a template function so you can reuse it for other `vector` types: `template<typename T> bool vector_contains_item(std::vector<T> const &vec, T const &item) { return std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item) != vec.end(); }` And then use a template parameter for the container itself so you are not limited to just `std::vector`: `template<typename C, typename T> bool contains_item(C const &container, T const &item) { return std::find(std::begin(container), std:end(container), item) != std::end(container); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I thought of those but refrained. Didn't want to make the OP's code any more complex than necessary. In our production code, we use a function named `is_in_container` whose implementation is exactly what you have for `contains_item`.